jQuery DataTable AJAX stuck on Loading
Cannot get past the 'Loading...' message in DataTables with Ajax. I have never used DataTables with AJAX before so this could be something simple.
Here is the HTML and jQuery:
<div id="studentDiv">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="StudentGrid" name="StudentGrid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>StudentID</th>
                <th>ShoppingCartID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#StudentGrid').DataTable(
                {
                    ajax: {
                        url: '/DataTableReload?handler=LoadStudent', 
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        dataSrc: 'data'
                    },
                    "autoWidth": false,
                    "width": "55%",
                    "language": { "search": "Find" },
                    "oLanguage": { "sEmptyTable": "No students"},
                    "columnDefs":
                        [
                            { data: "FirstName", "width": "70px", "targets": 0 },
                            { data: "LastName", "width": "70px", "targets": 1 },
                            { data: "StudentID", "width": "70px", "targets": 2 },
                            { data: "ShoppingCartID", "width": "70px", "targets": 3 },
                        ]
                })
        });

and here is the OnGet code in the DataTableReload page:
public JsonResult OnGetLoadStudent(string parms) {
    List<StudentData> students = new List<StudentData>();
    int studentId = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss"));
    students.Add(new StudentData((++studentId).ToString(), "Jim", "Miller", "555555"));
    students.Add(new StudentData((++studentId).ToString(), "Tim", "Thomas", "123456"));
    students.Add(new StudentData((++studentId).ToString(), "Zeb", "Zagreb", "787878"));

    AjaxResponse ajaxResponse = new AjaxResponse(students);
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ajaxResponse);
    return new JsonResult(json);
}
 public class AjaxResponse {
     public AjaxResponse(List<StudentData> Data) {
         data = Data;
     }

     public List<StudentData> data { get; set; }
 }
 public class StudentData {

     public StudentData(
         string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string shoppingCartID) {
         StudentID = studentID;
         FirstName = firstName;
         LastName = lastName;
         ShoppingCartID = shoppingCartID;
     }

     public string? StudentID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public string? FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public string? LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public string? ShoppingCartID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
 }

The json argument in 'return new JsonResult(json)' looks like this (and the return executes):
{"data":[
{"StudentID":"81744","FirstName":"Jim","LastName":"Miller","ShoppingCartID":"555555"},
{"StudentID":"81745","FirstName":"Tim","LastName":"Thomas","ShoppingCartID":"123456"},
{"StudentID":"81746","FirstName":"Zeb","LastName":"Zagreb","ShoppingCartID":"787878"}
]}

I have seen some examples where the dataSrc is defined as a function. Is that needed?

My suggestion (but its not the answer) is to use the Network tab of the browser Console and see what is going on there. Is the ajax url returning data or is it a server side issue? You should gleen more info from that.

Thanks for the tip. The Network tab shows the traffic is OK - it says:
Request URL: https://localhost:7076/DataTableReload
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK

Further if I change datasrc to this:
function (data) { console.log(data); return data; }
the console shows the exact same json as I have shown from the OnGet watch.

And the solution is to change dataSrc as follows:
dataSrc: function (data) { return JSON.parse(data); }

Then of-course the OnGet ajaxResponse should not be placing 'data' at the top of the returned json. The json can be just the list of records itself at the top level, i.e.
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(students);

